# ¿ Como cambiar color de fuentes en un mismo texto con CSS?

Tags: css, color, fuentes

agradezco de antemano su apoyo. Quisiera saber como puedo en un mismo texto cambiar los colores:

Ejemplo:  Mobil
- Todas las letras son de color azul excepto la letra o que es de color rojo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: favor de leer [ask] y checar el [tour], no solo importa poner la duda sino además mostrar que has intentado

Answer (score 1):

No lo explicas muy bien pero imagino que te refieres a esto:
Si colocas un `sup` dentro de un `p` por ejemplo desde css puedes accederlo de manera distinta observa:

```css
 #ejemplo p{
     color:blue;
     }
     #ejemplo sup{
     color:red;
     }
```

```html
<p id="ejemplo">M<sup>o</sup>bil</p>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo, logre hacerlo

Comment: <sup> es una etiqueta  para añadir superíndices. A parte del efecto que tiene, es semánticamente poco apropiado en este caso. Un <span> sería más apropiado ya que CSS no nos aporta un selector tipo :nth-letter, que sería lo idóneo para no añadir marcado.

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas envolver al `O` en un elemento `<span>` por ejemplo. Esto lo puedes hacer utilizando expresiones regulares. En el CSS cambias el estilo de los elementos

```
<span>: #elP span{color:red}
```

```js
let texto = elP.innerHTML; 
let nuevoTexto = texto.replace(/([O])/g, "<span>$1</span>")
elP.innerHTML = nuevoTexto;
```

```css
body {
    background:black;
    font-family:sans-serif
} 

#elP{color:skyBlue;font-size:40px; font-weight:bold}
#elP span{color:red}
```

```html
<p id="elP">MOBIL</p>
```

Comment: Gracias, utilice el span y resultó ideal.